# Comparing two distinct characters based only on their case

Tags: java

I want to compare two separate characters on their case only.  For example 'a' == 'b' would return true. Where as 'A' == 'a' would be false.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char)

Comment: Dont understand the problem here. Java character comparison default behavior is case sensitive. So what you need is already achieved by "==". What more do you need?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Character.isUpperCase( x ) == Character.isUpperCase( y ).
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the Java API for `Character` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char)).

```
char a = ...;
char b = ...;
boolean sameCaseStyle = Character.isUpperCase(a) == Character.isUpperCase(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Checks Uppercase
if variable.isUpperCase(str.charAt(index)) && variable.isUpperCase(str.charAt(index))
{
    //set variable true
}
```

For lowercase I am not too entirely sure how to implement that. I will get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this..

```
boolean func(char x,char y){
if(Character.isUpperCase(x)==Character.isUpperCase(y))
return true;
if(Character.isLowerCase(x)==Character.isLowerCase(y))
return true;
else return false;
}
```

Comment: the same as (assuming static import) `boolean func(char x, char y){ return  ( isUpperCase(x) && isUpperCase(y) ) || (isLowerCase(x) && isLowerCase(y)) );`